# Couchbase - Elasticsearch search issue

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I've followed the Couchbase - ElasticSearch tutorial integration and I'm testing it with the beer-sample bucket.

I have an issue.

I can do a query like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "doc.name": "IPA"
        }
    }
}
```

but if I search like that:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": { }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "doc.name": "IPA" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't obtain any result.

With other string field I don't have problems, for example, the "type" : "beer"

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "doc.type": "beer"
        }
    }
}

{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": { }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": { "doc.name": "beer" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your analyzer. For strings, the default analyzer lowercases the imput. So, IPA is indexed as ipa.

A term filter does not analyze your imput, and thus, you search for IPA and in your index, you have ipa --> IPA != ipa , and thus, the document do not match.

The match query, on the other end, analyzes your input using the analyzer that was set for the field, thus, your input is lowercased and you search for ipa.

I hope it makes sense.